# Add / Update record from textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I have a form with some textboxes that I have bound to a datasource, in this case named JobDataBindingSource. I have added a Binding navigator bound to the same datasource. I can scroll through the records and they appear correctly in the textboxes. I can hit the BindingNavigatorAddNewItem button, the textboxes clear for input. When I input  the new data it never saves.

I have tried this

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
Me.Job_DataTableAdapter.Update(Me.TravelerDataSet1.Job_Data)
End Sub

But it doesn't update the data in the database. It will display it in a datagridview until the app is closed. How do I get it to save the new data?

JobDataBindingSource AllowNew is set to True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` before saving the data. Until that is done, any edits you have done on the current record will not be committed to the underlying `DataTable`. `EndEdit` will be called implicitly if you navigate to a different record but if you don't do that then you have to call it explicitly. The explicit call won't hurt if there is no pending edit.

Note that you normally wouldn't do it when leaving a single `TextBox` if the user needs to enter multiple field values into the record.